# Change text style programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the text style to bold when user checks the bold checkbox but I am unable to do that. Text appears normally even after selecting the checkbox.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="bold"
    android:id="@+id/bold"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
    android:checked="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        checkBox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.bold);
        if(checkBox.isChecked())
            editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `OnCheckedChangeListener` and change the typeface there.

For a bold and a italic checkbox you could do something like this:

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean checked) {
        Typeface typeface = editText.getTypeface();

        switch(button.getId()) {
            case R.id.bold:
                if(typeface.isItalic()) {
                    editText.setTypeface(typeface, checked?Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC:Typeface.ITALIC);
                } else {
                    editText.setTypeface(typeface, checked?Typeface.BOLD:Typeface.NORMAL);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.italic:
                if(typeface.isBold()) {
                    editText.setTypeface(typeface, checked?Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC:Typeface.BOLD);
                } else {
                    editText.setTypeface(typeface, checked?Typeface.ITALIC:Typeface.NORMAL);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};

bold.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
italic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.If we have multipe checkboxes like one for bold,one for italic then we have to set multiple listners?

Comment: either that or one listener that looks at the `button.getId()` and does different things based on it

Comment: can you explain it further with example actually I am new to android

Comment: Added some more code, but since we're no longer in scope of your question, you should ask another question if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In android, you can change the text style of any XML widget by using the following attribute:

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

You can also use:

```
android:textStyle="italic"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

For italics and both bold and italics respectfully.

You can also use:

```
editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

This must be called from an `onCreate` method using the following:

```
XML:
android:onClick="makeBold"

Activity:
public void makeBold(View V) {
 if(checkBox.isChecked())
    editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to change style Programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You've to add a listener to the checkbox, so it detects when the status of the checkbox has changed, and then set the appropriate typeface:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
            editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            } else {
            editText.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.If we have multiple check boxes like one for bold,one for italic then we have to set multiple listeners?

Comment: Yes, just set a listener for every checkbox, and you can also check the status of a checkbox inside the listeners...

Comment: There is no any other better alternative?